# BertTokenizer - when encoding and decoding sequences extra spaces appear

Tags: python, pytorch, tokenize, torch, bert-language-model

When using Transformers from HuggingFace I am facing a problem with the encoding and decoding method.

I have a the following string:

```
test_string = 'text with percentage%'
```

Then I am running the following code:

```
import torch
from transformers import BertTokenizer

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')

test_string = 'text with percentage%'

# encode Converts a string in a sequence of ids (integer), using the tokenizer and vocabulary.
input_ids = tokenizer.encode(test_string)
output = tokenizer.decode(input_ids)
```

And the output looks like this:

```
'text with percentage %'
```

With an extra space before the %. I have tried the extra arguments like `clean_up_tokenization_spaces`  but this is for something different.

How what should I use in the decoding and encoding to get exactly the same text before and after. This also happens for other special signs.

Comment: I don't think the BERT tokenization process is 100% reversible, as you've noticed.  Why do you need it to be?  There may be other ways to accomplish what you want, e.g. by keeping around the original string instead of reconstructing it from tokens.

Comment: In contrast, things like https://github.com/kovalevfm/SubTokenizer actually are fully reversible.  I wish BERT was careful about this, but attention to detail in text segmentation seems to be a "production" issue not a "research" issue :(

Comment: This is just a snippet from my script to show the problem. In between I am doing question answering and what i would like to achieve is a fully traceable text

Comment: Ah, so ideally you would have something like https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/1274.  Assuming you're okay with snapping answer spans to whole words, you can use something like https://bistring.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python/Tokenizer.html to split into words while keeping track of string indexes, then just use `BertTokenizer` to get subwords

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to use BERT for token classification in order to find a span in your original string, then one workaround is to use `BertTokenizerFast` with the option `return_offsets_mapping=True`.

```
test_string = 'text with percentage%'

tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
tokens = tokenizer(test_string, return_offsets_mapping=True)
input_ids = tokens.data["input_ids"]

span_start_index, span_stop_index = some_model(input_ids)
```

Then once you get the token classification results, you can do something like

```
predicted_span = test_string[tokens.encodings[0].offsets[span_start_index][0]:tokens.encodings[0].offsets[span_stop_index][1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

According to https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/1274 they're working on it. hopefully there will be a solution sometime next week.

Answer (score 0):

One method of combining percentage and %, but I am unsure if it is useful for you.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
test_string = 'text with percentage%'
test_string = test_string.split()

collect_tokens = []
for string in test_string:
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(string)
    for index in range(1, len(tokens)):
        if "##" not in tokens[index]:
            tokens[index] = "##"+tokens[index]
    collect_tokens += tokens

# encode tokens to input_ids
input_ids = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(collect_tokens)

# decode
output = tokenizer.decode(input_ids)
```